# Package to create TikZ Figures from R

Tags: tikz-pgf, r

I am wondering if there is a recommended package in order to create TikZ figures in R.

In the paste I have used [Matlab2TikZ](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz) to create TikZ figures in MATLAB - and I was hoping that there would be something similar for R.

Comment: google suggests http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tikzdevice-demo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [tikzDevice](http://crantastic.org/packages/tikzDevice), although there is not currently an official release on CRAN of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this very useful package has only one developer, and he does not seem to be active recently.